# Foreignkeyfield - verbose name not shown in form

Tags: python, django, django-models

my `verbose_name` of a foreignkeyfield isn't printed in my forms. (I create the modelforms via `modelformset_factory`

model

```
class MOrders(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField('Bestellmenge', null=True, blank=True)
    order_date = models.DateField('Bestelldatum')
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    m_product_types = models.ForeignKey(MProductTypes)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'm_orders'
        verbose_name = 'Bestellung'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Bestellungen'
        unique_together = (('id','order_date','m_product_types'))
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.order_date)
```

`verbose_name` of `m_product_types` is set. B

```
class MProductTypes(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField('Bestand',null=True, blank=True)
    m_products = models.ForeignKey(MProducts, verbose_name='Produkt')
    m_sizes = models.ForeignKey(MSizes, verbose_name='Groesse')
    m_colors = models.ForeignKey(MColors, verbose_name='Farbe')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Produktart'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Produktarten'
        db_table = u'm_product_types'
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using the latest Django version from trunk.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
m_product_types = models.ForeignKey(MProductTypes, 
                                    verbose_name = u'Produktart',
                                   )
```

Comment: verbose_name_plural gives me a exception. the singular verbose_name works. Thanks leoluk thought the verbose name on the Foreign Model is enough

Comment: @onigunn So having `verbose_name` defined in the `Meta` of the ForeignKey's model is not enough then?

Comment: @onigunn it is enough for the referenced model itself, if you set it only in  Meta, it will affect the display in the main Django admin panel, but if you want to see it in the field where you select the referenced model(select box), you need to set verbose_name for the ForeginKey as well.